# Modify multiple columns in single Alter Table query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to modify multiple columns in one sql query? For example I want to change the column definition of multiple columns in single table as follows. I am using SQL server 2012.

```
ALTER TABLE [Department]     
ALTER COLUMN [DepartmentName] VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
[ProjectManagerName] VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
[AccountManagerName] VARCHAR(200) NULL
```

Comment: No, also there's no need to do this. If you want to do this all at the same time, then simple wrap all the alter statements in the same transaction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alter multiple columns in one time - impossible.

You could create Temp table with your edited columns, copy data from source table to temp table, drop your source table and rename temp table.

Comment: It is possible in oracle :

ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD (column_1 column_definition,
       column_2 column_definition,
       ...
       column_n column_definition);

Answer (score 6):

It is **not possible** to do multiple ALTER column for a table.

You have to alter them one by one like

```
ALTER TABLE Department ALTER COLUMN [DepartmentName] VARCHAR(200) NULL;
ALTER TABLE Department ALTER COLUMN [ProjectManagerName] VARCHAR(200) NULL;
ALTER TABLE Department ALTER COLUMN [ProjectManagerName] VARCHAR(200) NULL;
ALTER TABLE Department ALTER COLUMN [AccountManagerName] VARCHAR(200) NULL;
```